# flutter firestore only see posts of people you follow

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There is a user collection, there is a uid attribute and a uid list follower list. There is a post collection. There is an id unique and uid attribute that equalt to user uid who created post.How can I do that the user I want to see only the posts of the person they follow?

Comment: This topic has come up a few times before already, so I recommend looking here: https://www.google.com/search?q=flutter+firestore+only+see+posts+of+people+you+follow. You'll also note that none of these have a good authoritative answer, so I doubt there's a great solution.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ['in'](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) operator to retrieve posts whose creator is included in the list of followed users.

```
final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

try {
  // Get the specified user document from Firestore
  final userSnapshot = await firestore
      .collection('userCollection')
      .doc('userId')
      .get();

  // Check if the user document exists
  if (userSnapshot.exists) {
    // Get the list of followedUsers from the user data
    final followedUsers = List<String>.from(userSnapshot.data()['followedUsers']);

    // Query Firestore for every Post document that was created by any followedUsers
    final posts = await firestore
        .collection('postsCollection')
        .where('creator', whereIn: followedUsers)
        .get();

    
  } else {
    print('User not found.');
  }
} catch (e) {
  print('Error retrieving posts: $e');
}
```

Comment: I read articles on stackoverflow, if the length of the list of my followers exceeds 10, should I stop this?

Comment: The limit on values in an `in` clause is 30 nowadays.

Comment: That's true, I've read about a limitation. I don't know the exact amount, but in that case you could do several queries spliting the users each 10. Then just merge the posts together

Answer (score 0):

you can store the uids of the persons he follows in his doc and then show the posts accordingly to these uids.

Comment: I read articles on stackoverflow, if the length of the list of my followers exceeds 10, should I stop this?